# Cookies not being set across different ports under same domain

Tags: node.js, cookies

I have 2 apps running under the *localhost* domain

- The first one is a NestJS backend that at the same time serves an angular app as static files (running on **http://localhost:3000**)
- The second app is the angular app itself, on its dev server (running on **http://localhost:4200**)

the problem is that when I log in using the app from **http://localhost:3000** The `refresh_token` *cookie* is set correctly, but when I try to do the same from  **http://localhost:4200** the *cookie* isn't set.

between **http://localhost:4200** and **http://localhost:3000** the *cookie* is shared and I can inspect it from `Chrome DevTools`

I thought it might be a CORS issue but the preflight request are working as expected and I can get a response from the API

- I've tried the API with the postman and it works correctly

maybe it has something to do with the cookie config and how different ports are handled when setting cookies in  the browser

my nestJs CORS config

```js
app.enableCors({
    origin:
      process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
        ? process.env.PROD_DOMAIN
        : [
            `http://${process.env.DEV_DOMAIN}:4200`,
            `http://${process.env.DEV_DOMAIN}:3000`,
          ],
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  });
```

where `DEV_DOMAIN` and `PROD_DOMAIN` are env variables

```
PROD_DOMAIN=movies-actors-graph.herokuapp.com
DEV_DOMAIN=localhost
```

this is how Im setting the cookies on the controller that handles the `/login` endpoint

```js
 res.cookie('refresh_token', tokens.refresh_token, {
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: 'strict',
        secure: true, //!disable if testing on postman
        domain:
          process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
            ? process.env.PROD_DOMAIN
            : process.env.DEV_DOMAIN,
        maxAge: parseInt(process.env.JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRATION),
      });
```

as I've already mentioned, the problem is that *cookie* is being set correctly when using the **http://localhost:3000** static app to communicate to the Backend (which is in the same port) but when using the **http://localhost:4200** app the cookie is not set

this is the `Reponse Header` from the request when it is made from **http://localhost:3000**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 256
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 15 Nov 2022 15:41:59 GMT
ETag: W/"100-...."
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Set-Cookie: refresh_token=asd123; Max-Age=86400; Domain=localhost; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 16 Nov 2022 15:41:59 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict
Vary: Origin
X-Powered-By: Express
```

this is the `Reponse Header` from the request when it is made from **http://localhost:4200**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 256
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 15 Nov 2022 15:44:06 GMT
ETag: W/"100-..."
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Set-Cookie: refresh_token=asd123; Max-Age=86400; Domain=localhost; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 16 Nov 2022 15:44:06 GMT; HttpOnly; Secure; SameSite=Strict
Vary: Origin
X-Powered-By: Express
```

As @cmbuckley suggested I tried making a subsequent request from **http://localhost:4200** client with `withCredentials: true` as follows

```
//authService
...
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
refresh() {
    return this.http
      .post(
        environment.backendUrl + '/auth/refresh',
        {},
        {
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      )
      .pipe(shareReplay());
  }
}
```

the `Cookie` is successfully received and handled by the server controller and re-issuing a new refresh_token `Cookie` which, this time is correctly displayed in the cookies list under the Application tab on `Chrome Devtools`

I tried making the API call to `/auth/login` from **http://localhost:4200** client as well and this time the `Cookie`  was correctly displayed in the aforementioned `Chrome Devtools` tab

- I haven't changed the cookies nor the CORS settings of my backend
- It makes me think it might have been a visual bug on `Chrome Devtools` side rather than a `Cookie` problem, because it works as intended

If you are curious about this issue and want to try it out I'm providing the repo of my project below
https://github.com/AlejoTorres2001/actors-movies-graph

Comment: what do the HTTP responses look like in Postman? Does the Set-Cookie header appear in both cases? Does it look different between the 2?

Comment: I've added the response headers for both cases they look the same to me

Comment: You say the "cookie isn't set" in one of the examples. What do you mean by that? In both those cases the cookie is "set" (though I notice that they have the `Secure` flag which would not be sent for http requests)

Comment: What I meant by that is, when using the **http://localhost:3000** app, the cookie is set correctly in the browser, however when I use the **http://localhost:4200** app, which is in fact the angular dev server of the client app the cookie is not set in the browser, regarding the fact that both Response headers contains the ````Set-Cookie```` option

Comment: the ````Secure```` flag  makes the cookie only available through HTTPS connections, been localhost as the only exception (if I'm not wrong) That is why I turned it off when testing the API using another client, like ````PostMan````

Comment: Does Chrome show any warning by the Set-Cookie header in the Network tab? Here’s a forced example using an invalid domain attribute: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHeXd.png

Comment: there is no error/warning in the Devtools

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249658/discussion-between-cmbuckley-and-forshank).